# Comprehension scheme confusion

Tags: set-theory, axioms

Comprehension scheme: for every formula $\phi(s,t)$ with free variables $s$ and $t$, set $x$, and parameter $p$, there exists a set $y = \{u \in x : \phi(u,p)\}$

> Question: why not "for every formula $\phi(s)$ with free variable $s$, set $x$, there exists $y = \{u\in x: \phi(u)\}$?

I don't understand why a second variable is assumed and what role $p$ plays

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to have access to parameters. For example, if you want to talk about something definable in the real numbers, the language of set theory does not have access to the language of the real numbers or to the real numbers themselves.

Moreover, there is no "specific set" which is $\Bbb R$, instead we prove theorems about a variety of structures in a specific signature, and what $\sf ZFC$ proves is that every such structure will satisfy such and such statements.

So if you want to say, for example, that $x$ is the unique real number which is the length of the arc from $-1$ to $1$ in $\Bbb R^2$, that every point on that arc is of distance exactly $1$ (in simpler terms, $x$ is exactly $\pi$), then you need to specify what *are* the real numbers for *this* instance of the discussion.

This is the parameter $p$. It holds inside it the whole language, interpretation and so on.

And this is just one example, of course. But if you want set theory to be a foundational theory, then you need to at least make it easy for people to be able and define sets "in everyday mathematics" using set theory. And allowing parameters is the easiest way to ensure that this is possible.

Comment: I am still a beginner so I don't understand what it means to (not have access to the language of real numbers). Isn't it through set theory that we construct the real numbers? (to define $0 = \emptyset$, $1 = \{0\}$, etc? then proceed to integers and rational then reals?) why would the language of set theory not have access to the language of real numbers if the reals themselves are set theoretic objects? This is probably a stupid question, but bear with me

Comment: On the other hand, you do not really need parameters. (Do you know the precise reference for this? It is due to Lévy.) A recent presentation of this result can be seen [here](http://wwwmath.uni-muenster.de/logik/Personen/rds/ZFC_without_parameters.pdf).

Comment: @Andres: I once asked Azriel if he can find the original paper for me. He asked me to remind him a few days later, and I guess I forgot to follow through on this. I'm meeting him tomorrow, so that seems like a good time to ask again.

Comment: @madmatician: That is *a* canonical way of constructing the reals (start from the natural numbers via finite ordinals, define the integers, then the rationals, then the reals via Dedekind-cuts). But nevertheless, there are *other* ways to construct the real numbers. Just use Cauchy sequences instead of Dedekind-cuts, and you already have on your hands an entirely different *set*.

Comment: So it is possible to have the real numbers as just set theoretic objects, although other constructions are possible. Now doesn't this also apply to anything which can reasonably be called a parameter? I mean what is anything outside set theory? Can you give me a concrete example of something which can't by any means be regarded as a set theoretic object?

Comment: @madmatician: No. You can treat more or less anything as a set. And your parameter is *also* a set. Let me ask you this, *what* is the language of set theory?

Comment: @AsafKaragila sadly I can't answer that because I nearly have no idea what I am talking about. Like I said I am a beginner and I am just trying to understand your answer, and it is not yet clear to me why something called a parameter should be spoken about

Comment: @madmatician: It is hard to understand how *formal* axioms interact with set theory if you don't even know the rules of the language.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough replies. I am reading from Ciesielski (set theory for working mathematician). Do you think I should start somewhere else if I want to understand things better?

Comment: @madmatician: If you are just starting with set theory, I'd say that Enderton's Elements of Set Theory should be a good start. I heard good things about Goldrei's book also.