# Countable transitive model of finitely many axioms of ZFC.

Tags: logic, set-theory

Let $M$ be a countable transitive model of finitely many axioms of $ZFC$. Let $C=\{p:F\to 2\mid F \text{ is a finite subset of }\omega\}$. Now for each $n\in \omega$, define $D_n = \{p\in C \mid n\in \operatorname{Dom}(p)\}$. Now I was told that we can choose the axioms of $ZFC$ such that $D_n\in M \forall n\in \omega$, but I don't understand this. We would need $\omega$ instances of the comprehension scheme in order to have $D_n \in M$ for all  $n\in \omega$, no? So $M$ is not just a model of finitely many axioms of $ZFC$ no?

Comment: No, you can prove a theorem that states that all $D_n$ are sets. By a theorem I mean a single explicit first-order sentence, not a schema, and accordingly its proof only uses finitely many axioms..

Comment: I agree that there is a way to see that these are sets by using infinitely many instances of comprehension. That's not what I suggest in the comment above.

Comment: Oh, I see and do you have a hint on how to prove that $D_n$ are actually sets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really just need one instance of Comprehension. If you needed infinitely many instances, then you wouldn't even been able to prove that $\{D_n\mid n\in\omega\}$ is a set in the outer universe.

The thing to notice is that Comprehension allows for parameters. Here the parameter is $n$. So as long as $\omega\subseteq M$, you only need the one instance of comprehension to get *all* of these sets. And if you also have the power set axiom, at least for the set $C$, then you can also show that $\{D_n\mid n\in\omega\}$ is also a set in $M$.

Comment: I see. This is interesting. In [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1885286/340973), he says as you that we can allow for parameters. But what would be the formula $\phi$ in $\{u\in x: \phi(u,p)\}$? Sorry, I am a total beginner

Comment: You already gave the formula. Just $p\in\operatorname{dom}(u)$. How you decode domains depends exactly on how you encode functions.

Comment: And actually we have $\omega\subseteq M$ as soon as $M$ is a model of $ZFC$ right? And also, we get by one instance of the comprehension scheme not only that $\{D_n\vert n\in \omega\}$ are sets but even $\{D_n\vert n\in M\}$ are all sets right?

Comment: As soon as it is a model of some very small fragment of ZFC, yes.

Comment: Thank you. Is the end of my last comment correct?

Comment: I mean, if $\omega\subseteq M$, then it's the same set, otherwise, what does it mean for $m\in M\setminus\omega$ to be the index of a dense open set like that?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I meant if $M$ was not a countable model

Comment: Well, again, what does $D_m$ even mean?